# Got This Error after Installing Darkest Theme from marketplace in STS Spring

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling".
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.getSavedContainer(org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject)" because the return value of "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.getBuildPathManager()" is null

Any idea what is this error about ?

Comment: I would suggest to raise an issue here: https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core

Comment: Ok, Sure. I i will ask there